# Number rows based on similar columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, group-by

How to number rows base on similar elements in rows. Eg. From this table

```
Id ColA  ColB
1.   A.       B
2.   A.       C
 3.  A.        c
4.   A.       B
5.   B.       A
6.   B.       A
```

I wish get the following table

```
  Id ColA  ColB. Grouped by
 1.   A.       B.     1
 2.   A.       C.      2
 3.  A.        c.     2
 4.   A.       B.     1
 5.   B.       A.     3
 6.   B.       A.     3
```

The logic is: the rows with Id 1and 4 have similar elements in columns A and B so they get number the same group number. The number itself doesn't play role.
So for the rows with Id 2 and 3 they get the same number.

Comment: Can you explain the logic of how you've reached this result? It's a bit cryptic to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to just [`rank`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions123.htm) the rows according to both columns. Since rows 2 and 3 seem to have the same `"Grouped by"` regardless of the different case of `C` vs. `c` (assuming this isn't a typo), you'd have to rank them according to the [`upper`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions206.htm) (or [`lower`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions081.htm), for that matter) of the columns:

```
SELECT colA, colB, 
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY UPPER(colA), UPPER(colB)) AS "Grouped by"
FROM   my_table
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But are you sure that this rank doesn't return always 1 as "grouped by" value ? I mean do you need partition clause ?

Comment: @user3260813 - yes, you are correct - I removed the (wrong) `partition by` clause.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this.

```
select p.id,p.cola,p.colb,se2.counter  from 
(SELECT se.*,ROWNUM as counter
FROM (SELECT  COLA,COLB FROM table1
GROUP BY  COLA,COLB) se
) se2, table1 p
where 
p.cola = se2.cola
and
p.colb = se2.colb
```